# Passing a pointer into methods in C++ resulting in weird output

Tags: c++, c-strings, function-definition, toupper

I am trying to convert a string of characters to Upper case by passing a pointer into a toUpper method that I have created. The logic seems to be fine but I get a weird output like ìëïà. Any ideas where I have gone wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h> 

using namespace std;

void toUpper(char *);

int main()
{
    char name[80];
    char *namePtr = name;

    cout << "Enter a name :";
    cin >> name;

    toUpper(namePtr);
    cout << "The string in Upper Case is: " << name << endl;


}

void toUpper(char *p)
{

    int asciiValue; 

    // Loop through each char in the string
    for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(p); i++)
    {
        
        asciiValue = (int) p[i];

        if(asciiValue >= 97 && asciiValue <= 122)
        {
            asciiValue = asciiValue + 32;
            p[i] = asciiValue;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that you can use literals like `'a'` and `'z'` instead of `97` and `122` to avoid magic numbers. Also note that this algorithm doesn't always work. C++ does not guarantee that the character encoding will be ASCII or even that the letters of the alphabet will be encoded with sequential values.

Comment: Which "uninialized memory", exactly, are you referring to, @tarick? And what do you mean by "int size block of memory"? There is nothing of that sort here, the bug is something else.

Comment: Substract 32, not add.

Comment: This is a fairly simple typo, but where you "have gone wrong here" is not using a debugger, which allows you to run your program one line at a time and see exactly what's happening. Have you ran this code in your debugger and observe how this algorithm turns out to be, one character at a time, yet? If not, why not?

Comment: 1) Use `std::string`.  2) Look up `std::tolower`.  3) Use `std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), tolower)`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews should be an answer, no? I don't think the obvious should be excluded just because it appears obviosu that OP is carrying out an exercise. OP has gone wrong already when they did not use `std::string`

Comment: Since the code in question is entirely C, here’s a (almost entirely) C solution: `for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = std::toupper(*p);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem boils down to bad magic numbers, which makes it nearly impossible to tell even from a close look because they're magic numbers!

Instead, I'd use character literals to make things obvious:

```
if(asciiValue >= 'a' && asciiValue <= 'z')
{
    asciiValue = asciiValue + ('a' - 'A');
    p[i] = asciiValue;
}
```

Now it should be pretty apparent that you're adding the wrong value! It should instead be:

```
asciiValue = asciiValue + ('A' - 'a');
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel stupid. I've been looking at his for hours. I thought I made a mistake with the pointer.

Comment: @Clan which is exactly why I harped on your magic numbers. Throwing them around is almost always a recipe for pull-your-hair-out bugs.You know for next time! :)

Comment: @scohe001 nice one.  FUll in the spirit of K&R.  But are you aware that this doesn't work for and an ISO 8859-3 encoding, with multiple ranges of lowercase letters, and different offsets between upper and lower case? The difference between 'Ŭ' and 'ŭ' is for example -32 but between 'Ż' and 'ż' it's -16 . ANd I don not even mention unicode ;-)

Comment: @Chris every time I post a character arithmetic answer I get one of these comments. I agree with you entirely and this wouldn't get past a code review with production code. That being said, I've tried to show OP their error without getting lost in the weeds (and their variable name is `asciiValue`, so we're probably fine here). I could add a part on the "right" way to do this, but at that point I'd just be giving a lesser version of the already great answers below.

Comment: @scohe001 I'm sorry if I did upset you. This was not the intent.  But I'm using daily a couple of languages that use some weird characters that give different results with different encodings. Sometimes these characters are not transformed a they should.  Sometimes they are even rejected because not recognised as printable chars. I guess that all the people who suffer daily or even get their name mutilated this way, are exactly the people who write you such comments ;-) So it's really not theoretic and therefore the isxxxx() toxxx() really deserve to get better known

Answer (score 3):

### Your code is non portable

This is non portable code. It is sure to work only with ASCII encoding.
Nevertheless,  here the corresponding non-portable solution:

```
       asciiValue = asciiValue - 32;   // - just move in the other direction
```

### How to do better?

Here some problems for your current code:

- The difference between upper and lowercase letters is not always 32. In EBCDIC,  for example,  the difference between upper and lowercase ordinary letters is `+64` instead of `-32`.
- The boundaries of lowercase might be different as well.
- With foreign languages using non ASCII locale,  you might have special characters that are in a different range than the normal letters (see for example [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1))  where you also have lowercase in the range 224 and 25' but with one exception.
- **In some encodings, you have even different rules for different sets of lowercases.**  Take [ISO 8859-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-3).  The difference between `'Ŭ'` and `'ŭ'` is -32 but between `'Ż'` and `'ż'` it's -16 .
- Finally,  chars are not guaranteed to be unsigned.  Your whole comparison logic might completely fail,  if you use an ISO-8859-1 encoding compined with a compiler that manages chars as signed chars.

A much safer approach is therefore to to use: [`isupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) and [`toupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)  which takes into account the locale.

As a side effect,  this will even facilitate migration to a full unicode compliant code, using the [templated version of these functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/toupper) or the [wide version](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towupper).

### And why don't you use real strings?

Your code is at risk of a buffer overflow, if someone types a name of 80 or more characters.  You'd need to make sure that cin does not take more characters than allowed.  But instead of telling you how to do this,  I suggest to use the safer `std::string` instead:

```
void toUpper(string &s)
{
    for(auto &p:s)              // Loop through each char in the string
        if (islower(p))         
            p =toupper(p);
}

int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter a name :";
    cin >> name;
    toUpper(name);
    cout << "The string in Upper Case is: " << name << endl;
}
```

[online demo](https://ideone.com/LSpnnS)

Comment: Even on EBCDIC systems, the difference between upper and lowercase letters is constant for every pair of letters. Using `+ ('A' - 'a')` would also provide a simple portable solution.

Comment: @scohe001 Maybe, but as soon as you're no longer in ASCII and use some ISO based locale, this will not work anymode.  Take  'é' and 'É'  for example;

Answer (score 1):

asciiValue = asciiValue - 32;

**Minus instead of plus**
Example:
ASCII value of "a" is 97

97 - 32 is 65 which is the ASCII value of uppercase A

Answer (score 1):

It seems in this if statement

```
    if(asciiValue >= 97 && asciiValue <= 122)
    {
        asciiValue = asciiValue + 32;
        p[i] = asciiValue;
    }
```

you are checking that the current symbol is a lower-case ASCII symbol.

But lower-case ASCII symbols have higher codes than upper-case ASCII symbols.

So instead of adding the magic number 32

```
        asciiValue = asciiValue + 32
```

you have to subtract it

```
        asciiValue = asciiValue - 32
```

For example the lower case ASCII symbol `'a'` has the code `97` while the upper case.symbol `'A'` has the code `65`.

But in any case your approach with magic numbers is bad because for example it will not work with EBCDIC symbol representations.

Also calling the function `strlen` in this case is inefficient.

And it is much better when the function returns pointer to the converted string.

The function can be declared and implemented the following way

```
#include <cctype>

//...

char * toUpper( char *s )
{
    for ( char *p = s; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( std::islower( static_cast<unsigned char>( *p ) ) )
        {
            *p = std::toupper( static_cast<unsigned char>( *p ) );
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `cctype`'s `touper()`, is the `if` statement even necessary? Won't `toupper()` just return the unmodified character if it can't uppercase it?

Comment: @scohe001 I think there is no difference because if remove the if statement then you need always do assignments.

Answer (score 0):

A more portable C++ solution is to use `std::transform` to transform the string to lower case:

```
std::string shouting = "AM I SHOUTING";
std::transform(shouting.begin(), shouting.end(), shouting.begin(), tolower);
std::cout << shouting << "\n";
```

This solution does not rely on ASCII encoding and will work with code sets where `std::tolower` is valid.

Comment: Side note: `tolower` can sometimes screw up if `char` is signed. [See the notes linked here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower#Notes).

Comment: This one is very elegant!  What albout replacing `tolower` with `[](auto c){return   tolower(c,std::locale());}`  ?

Comment: I haven't tried with a lambda.  Usually `std::lower` goes through the locale system.